# Not allowed to load local resource Microsoft Edge

Tags: html

So I am trying to load a video from my files and play it on my html window.
But when I load the site, the video does not play and the console tells me that I am not allowed to load a local resource. Here is my current html code to play the video:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="C:/users/zacle/Documents/VideoPlayer/uploads/SpideyZac.mp4">
</video>
```

Can anyone help me get rid of this error and actually play my video.

Comment: read it, pls - https://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2020/05/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-microsoft-edge/

Comment: Based on the src `C:/users/zacle/Documents/VideoPlayer/uploads/SpideyZac.mp4` its obvious that you are trying to load a source from outside the workspace. Thats  NO GO in any browser, or any place! Its a huge security risk! Such source you can laod either by making an API call and getting form another server, for example youtube, or simply saving the image INSIDE your workspace, for eample inside `videos` folder, and then using it. Plz read what s.kuznetsov linked you.

Comment: @Lith, Thats "NO GO" only when one doesn't know what they are doing. There should be an option to disable this feature, to able to test stuff. The group policy one is not that. Not being able to disable this in the browser settings is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Running you project from http means having a http server and running your project via `http://localhost`.